# GAWK for the Pi without the internet

Tags: networking

I need to install gawk for the Pi 2 without connecting to the internet for a class I am teaching on intranets.  Any ideas?   I can move the sources via a usb stick.

Comment: mawk is the version of awk usually installed.  Why not limit the lessons to a common subset of awk between mawk and gawk?

Comment: I'm trying to compile a routing package that requires gawk and will not compile with mawk.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are running Raspbian, download the deb package for [Jessie](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/armel/gawk/download)  or [Wheezy](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/armel/gawk/download) Copy it to the Pi (via flashdrive or card reader). Then install it:

```
dpkg -i name_of_downloaded_file.
```

Alternatively, you could use `awk` which I believe is preinstalled.